# Build failed with UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field <Section> error

Tags: java, json

In my JSON file I have defined customMetrics as

```json
"customMetricHeadings": [
  {
    "headingName": "CUSTOM VIEWABILITY",
    "customMetricCategory": "CUSTOM_VIEWABILITY"
  },
  {
    "headingName": "CUSTOM VIEWABILITY QI",
    "customMetricCategory": "CUSTOM_VIEWABILITY_QI"
  }
]
```

I have defined this customMetricCategory for different metrics in the same JSON file as

```json
{
  "columnName": "nonQualifiedForViewabilityAds4",
  "columnLabel": "Not viewable ads, Excl. Geo, ?????",
  "cellType": "COUNT",
  "columnWidth": "CHAR_17",
  "cellAggType": "SUM",
  "cellAggColumn": "",
  "customMetricCategory": "CUSTOM_VIEWABILITY_QI"
},
{
  "columnName": "nonQualifiedForViewabilityPct4",
  "columnLabel": "% Non quality: not viewable, Excl. Geo, ?????",
  "cellType": "TWO_PRECISION_PERCENT",
  "columnWidth": "CHAR_17",
  "cellAggType": "WEIGHTED_AVERAGE",
  "cellAggColumn": "nonQualifiedAds4",
  "customMetricCategory": "CUSTOM_VIEWABILITY_QI"
},
{
  "columnName": "nonQualifiedForBrandSafetyAds4",
  "columnLabel": "Failed brand safety ads, Excl. Geo, ?????",
  "cellType": "COUNT",
  "columnWidth": "CHAR_17",
  "cellAggType": "SUM",
  "cellAggColumn": "",
  "customMetricCategory": "CUSTOM_VIEWABILITY_QI"
},
{
  "columnName": "nonQualifiedForBrandSafetyPct4",
  "columnLabel": "% Non quality: failed brand safety, Excl. Geo, ?????",
  "cellType": "TWO_PRECISION_PERCENT",
  "columnWidth": "CHAR_17",
  "cellAggType": "WEIGHTED_AVERAGE",
  "cellAggColumn": "nonQualifiedAds4",
  "customMetricCategory": "CUSTOM_VIEWABILITY_QI"
},
{
  "columnName": "nonQualifiedForFraudAds4",
  "columnLabel": "Invalid traffic ads, Excl. Geo, ?????",
  "cellType": "COUNT",
  "columnWidth": "CHAR_17",
  "cellAggType": "SUM",
  "cellAggColumn": "",
  "customMetricCategory": "CUSTOM_VIEWABILITY_QI"
},
{
  "columnName": "nonQualifiedForFraudPct4",
  "columnLabel": "% Non quality: IVT, Excl. Geo, ?????",
  "cellType": "TWO_PRECISION_PERCENT",
  "columnWidth": "CHAR_17",
  "cellAggType": "WEIGHTED_AVERAGE",
  "cellAggColumn": "nonQualifiedAds4",
  "customMetricCategory": "CUSTOM_VIEWABILITY_QI"
},
{
  "columnName": "nonQualifiedForGeoAds4",
  "columnLabel": "Out of geo ads, Excl. Geo, ?????",
  "cellType": "COUNT",
  "columnWidth": "CHAR_17",
  "cellAggType": "SUM",
  "cellAggColumn": "",
  "customMetricCategory": "CUSTOM_VIEWABILITY_QI"
},
{
  "columnName": "nonQualifiedForGeoPct4",
  "columnLabel": "% Non quality: Out of geo, Excl. Geo, ?????",
  "cellType": "TWO_PRECISION_PERCENT",
  "columnWidth": "CHAR_17",
  "cellAggType": "WEIGHTED_AVERAGE",
  "cellAggColumn": "nonQualifiedAds4",
  "customMetricCategory": "CUSTOM_VIEWABILITY_QI"
}
```

While running the repo in my local, build is failing with the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CRBTemplates': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "customMetricCategory" (class com.integralads.crbworker.output.template.json.TemplateColumn), not marked as ignorable (6 known properties: "columnWidth", "columnName", "cellAggColumn", "cellAggType", "cellType", "columnLabel"])
 at [Source: (URL); line: 2170, column: 32] (through reference chain: com.integralads.crbworker.output.template.json.Template["columns"]->java.util.ArrayList[205]->com.integralads.crbworker.output.template.json.TemplateColumn["customMetricCategory"])
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:139)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:414)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1248)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1168)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
        ... 98 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "customMetricCategory" (class com.integralads.crbworker.output.template.json.TemplateColumn), not marked as ignorable (6 known properties: "columnWidth", "columnName", "cellAggColumn", "cellAggType", "cellType", "columnLabel"])
```

Do I need to define anything else for this customMetricCategory? How can I get rid of this error?

TemplateColumn.java class

```
package com.integralads.crbworker.output.template.json;

import com.integralads.crbworker.excel.core.ReportCell;
import com.integralads.crbworker.excel.core.ReportColumnWidth;

public class TemplateColumn {

    private String columnName;
    private String columnLabel;
    private ReportCell.CellType cellType;
    private ReportColumnWidth columnWidth;
    private ReportCell.CellAggType cellAggType;
    private String cellAggColumn;

    public String getColumnName() {
        return columnName;
    }

    public void setColumnName(String columnName) {
        this.columnName = columnName;
    }

    public String getColumnLabel() {
        return columnLabel;
    }

    public void setColumnLabel(String columnLabel) {
        this.columnLabel = columnLabel;
    }

    public ReportCell.CellType getCellType() {
        return cellType;
    }

    public void setCellType(ReportCell.CellType cellType) {
        this.cellType = cellType;
    }

    public ReportColumnWidth getColumnWidth() {
        return columnWidth;
    }

    public void setColumnWidth(ReportColumnWidth columnWidth) {
        this.columnWidth = columnWidth;
    }

    public ReportCell.CellAggType getCellAggType() {
        return cellAggType;
    }

    public void setCellAggType(ReportCell.CellAggType cellAggType) {
        this.cellAggType = cellAggType;
    }

    public String getCellAggColumn() {
        return cellAggColumn;
    }

    public void setCellAggColumn(String cellAggColumn) {
        this.cellAggColumn = cellAggColumn;
    }
}
```

Also there is a TemplateCustomMetricheading.java class also define for the customMetricCategory

```
package com.integralads.crbworker.output.template.json;

public class TemplateCustomMetricHeading {
    private String headingName;
    private CustomMetricCategory customMetricCategory;

    public String getHeadingName() {
        return headingName;
    }

    public void setHeadingName(String headingName) {
        this.headingName = headingName;
    }

    public CustomMetricCategory getCustomMetricCategory() {
        return customMetricCategory;
    }

    public void setCustomMetricCategory(CustomMetricCategory customMetricCategory) {
        this.customMetricCategory = customMetricCategory;
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be deserializing some list of POJOs.  Does this POJO class have field `customMetricCategory` field?

Comment: @AlexRudenko yes.



package com.integralads.crbworker.output.template.json;

public enum CustomMetricCategory {
    CUSTOM_VIEWABILITY,
    CUSTOM_VIEWABILITY_QI
}

Comment: Can you please add `TemplateColumn` code? Thanks!

Comment: @H.Tiwari, this is not a _field_, but definition of the enum.  Does the POJO have that enum field: `class TemplateColumn { CustomMetricCategory customMetricCategory; ... }`?

Comment: @AlexRudenko
I have added the files in the end of question itself. Please let me know anything else I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to get rid of the error:

1. Add the missing field `private CustomMetricCategory customMetricCategory` to the `TemplateColumn` class and implement related getter/setter to comply with the input JSON:

```java
public class TemplateColumn {

    private String columnName;
    private String columnLabel;
    private ReportCell.CellType cellType;
    private ReportColumnWidth columnWidth;
    private ReportCell.CellAggType cellAggType;
    private String cellAggColumn;
    private CustomMetricCategory customMetricCategory;
// ... getters/setters
}
```

---

2. Ignore failing on unknown properties when deserializing instances of `TemplateColumn` class.

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class TemplateColumn {
...
}
```